# Erro em readImage utilizando Imagick()

Tags: php, imagemagick

Estou tentando converter um pdf em imagem utilizando a biblioteca Imagick da seguinte forma:

```
<?
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
$imagick = new Imagick();
// O myfile se encontra na mesma pasta do arquivo que estou executando
$imagick->readImage('myfile.pdf');
$imagick->writeImages('myfile.jpg', false);
```

Estou tendo o seguinte erro:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message
>   'Unable to read the file: myfile.pdf' in /Users/myuser/teste.php:11
>   Stack trace:
>   0 /Users/myuser/teste.php(11): Imagick->readimage('myfile.pdf')
>   1 {main}   thrown in /Users/myuser/teste.php on line 11

O que poderia ser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente com o diretório completo para a imagem:

```
$image->readImage($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/dir_da_imagem/myfile.pdf');
$imagick->writeImages($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/dir_da_imagem/myfile.jpg', false);
```

Onde dir_da_imagem é o diretório relativo de `myfile.pdf`.
Fora isso, verifique as permissões do `myfile.pdf` e se o arquivo não está corrompido.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, fiz as alterações acima, dei permissão 777 para o arquivo também para garantir, testei com is_readable() para ter certeza de que o arquivo pode ser lido mais ainda não funcionou.

Comment: Você tem o Ghostscript (http://www.ghostscript.com/) instalado? Isso pode ser uma causa também. Aparentemente, o imagick utiliza o gs para converter PDFs.

Comment: Instalei usando:

**brew install php56-imagick --with-ghostscript**

reiniciei o apache também mas nada.